# HTML position sidebar next to content

Tags: html, web, screen, scale

i am currently trying to move my sidebar from below the content box to the right of it alongside it. No matter what i try it stays at a certain point no going up any higher. My website is [VAGUE LINES](http://www.vaguelines.com), where if you scroll down a bit u will be able to see exactly what i am saying.

Below is my css code thanks alot:

```
 h1
{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    letter-spacing:12px;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    border-top:1px solid rgb;
    margin-top:35px;
    color:#544E4F;
    font-weight:lighter;
}

hr
{
display:overline-block;
width:200px;
}

#header
{
background: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
}

#navigation ul li 
{
 display: inline; 
 padding-right: 30px;
}

#navigation ul li a
{
text-decoration: none;
padding: .3em 5em;
color: #000000;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: courier;
}


#navigation ul li a:hover
{
text-decoration: line-through;
}


.centeredImage
    {
    float: none;
    margin: 4% 0 2% 9%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    }

#main-content hr 
{
width :66%;
margin-left: 9%;
}

#main-content
{
width:80%;
padding-left: 113px;
padding-top: 20px;
}

#page-wrap {
    background: white;
    min-width: 780px;
    max-width: 1260px;
    margin: 10px auto;

    }
    #page-wrap #inside {
        margin: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

#sidebar{
border-top: 1px solid #99CC33;
    border-left: 1px solid #99CC33;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    position:absolute;
}

#main-content p
{
margin-left: 10%;
font-family: courier;
font-size: 14px;
}

#heading p
{
margin-left: 10%;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}

#sidebar p
{
margin-left: 10%;
font-family: courier;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#main-content
{
    float: left; // float element to the left side
    width:80%;
    padding-left: 113px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#sidebar{
    border-top: 1px solid #99CC33;
    border-left: 1px solid #99CC33;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0; // position element to the right
}
```

EDIT: Sorry. You wanted sidebar on the right.

Comment: Hey there, thanks alot for the reply!! The only problem is now the webpage has the sidebar on the left, where i am trying to position it on the right. Do you know how to do that? Thanks Alot again

Comment: Thanks heaps. You are a legend. now the only issue is, is that when i zoom out the sidebar doesnt stay grouped with the other content it moves over to the left why is that?

Comment: That's because sidebar is positioned absolutely. Remove position:absolute; and add float: right; Should help.

Comment: Hahahah, the problem now is that it has gone down to the bottom below the content box thanks

Comment: When element has padding or margin it adds up to the width of element. Remove all margins and padding for content and sidebar and it should work.